# Question on continuity and optimization

Tags: optimization, continuity, global-optimization

Let    $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is it true that, if    $$\lim_{||(x,y)||\to{\infty}}{f(x,y)}=-{\infty}$$ then $f$ has a global maximum on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I think that is true, but I don't know how to prove it. Can someone give me a proof or a counter-example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true.

As $\lim_{||(x,y)||\to{\infty}}{f(x,y)}=-{\infty}$, there is $N>0$ such that if $\|(x,y)\|>N$, then $f(x,y)<-|f(0,0)|-1$.

Now, observe that $K:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:\ \|(x,y)\|\le N\}$ is compact, so, since $f$ is continuous, [Weierstrass' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces) guarantees the existence of a maximum on $K$. Let $M:=\max_{x\in K} f(x)$.

If $f(0,0)\ge 0$, then $M\ge f(0,0)>-|f(0,0)|-1$, so $M$ is teh global Maximum of $f$.

If $f(0,0)<0$, then $M\ge f(0,0)=-|f(0,0)|>-|f(0,0)|-1$, and, again, $M$ is the global maximum of $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: why take $-|f(0,0)|-1$ instead of just $f(0,0)$?

Comment: It is more intuitive for me to take a negative value to use the limit property